# How to fix: problem with conflicting request when installing ansible

Tags: ansible, installation, yum, epel

whenever I try to install ansible doing: yum install ansible, after grabbing the epel-release repo, it throws an error saying:

```
Problem: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides python-setuptools needed by ansible-2.8.2-1.el7.noarch
  - nothing provides python-jinja2 needed by ansible-2.8.2-1.el7.noarch
  - nothing provides python-six needed by ansible-2.8.2-1.el7.noarch
  - nothing provides PyYAML needed by ansible-2.8.2-1.el7.noarch
  - nothing provides python2-cryptography needed by ansible-2.8.2-1.el7.noarch
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
```

Does anyone have any idea what this means/what I can do?

EDIT: I am using redhat8

Comment: on which OS are you doing this?

Comment: Hi did you solve the problem if yes please do tell me. i have been trying to install ansible in RHEL8 aws server but getting same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you enable the **epel**, you don't need to disable the other repositories.

On my centos7, I find python-setuptools in the **base** repository:

```
yum info python-setuptools
```

gives

```
...
Repo        : base/7/x86_64
...
```

and the **base** repository is one of the base repositories present on centos7 by default.

Comment: can you tell me exactly how can i enable that?

Answer (score 1):

Please check the version of linux version you are using and download the correct epel repos accordingly
In my case I was using the older linux version repos while I was on CENTOS 8
you can find the EPEL version for different flavors in the following link

For RHEL 8

```
yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm
```

to check the repos

```
sudo yum repolist
```

Finally installation of ansible

```
sudo yum install ansible

ansible --version
```

Hope this helps to answer the question